# apt-get upgrade fails because of glibc6

Tags: debian, upgrade, glibc

I cannot upgrade my system anymore. I get the following error. What can I do to resolve this problem?

```
 apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run `apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  binutils: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.11) but 2.7-18lenny7 is installed
            Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.3.2-1.1 is installed
  cpp-4.6: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.11) but 2.7-18lenny7 is installed
  gcc-4.6: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.11) but 2.7-18lenny7 is installed
  libc-bin: Breaks: libc6 (< 2.10) but 2.7-18lenny7 is installed
  libc-dev-bin: Depends: libc6 (> 2.13) but 2.7-18lenny7 is installed
                Recommends: manpages-dev but it is not installed
  libc6-dev: Depends: libc6 (= 2.13-30) but 2.7-18lenny7 is installed
  libquadmath0: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.10) but 2.7-18lenny7 is installed
```

When I run `apt-get -f install` I get the following error

```
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up libgcc1 (1:4.7.0-3) ...
FATAL: kernel too old
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgcc1.postinst: line 15:  3479 Segmentation fault      ldconfig
dpkg: error processing libgcc1 (--configure):
 subprocess post-installation script returned error exit status 139
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgcc1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: This might help a little - http://serverfault.com/questions/285511/debian-stable-cant-update-kernel-libc-wont-update.

Answer (score 0):

```
You might want to run `apt-get -f install' to correct these.
```

Comment: updated the question. new error

Comment: Please done use the *code* markup for emphasis ;)

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I just copied what he did. :P

Comment: @Bibhas: Oh, now I see it ;D My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to `wheezy` folled by `downgrade` to squeeze made it. Was a bit tricky, had to remove and reinstall some packages for this to work.